# Magento - get url of the logo for a frontend store in admin

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm building a Magento extension for the admin backend and I'm trying to retrieve the url of the logo for a frontend store.

I've tried the following code:

```
$logo_src = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src', $store_id);
$design = Mage::getDesign();
$logo_url = $design->getSkinUrl($logo_src);
```

But it returns the url of the logo for the admin backend.

Then I managed to get the right url using the following code:

```
$logo_src = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src', $store_id);
$design = Mage::getDesign();
$design->setArea('frontend');
$logo_url = $design->getSkinUrl($logo_src);
$design->setArea('adminhtml');
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to retrieve the logo url...

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419081/how-can-i-change-logo-of-magento-in-backend link. It might be help you.

Answer (score 1):

try your code inside the store emulation:

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

/*
 * Any code thrown here will be executed as we are currently running that store
 * with applied locale, design and similar
 */

//Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to be much more cleaner than my solution...

Comment: thats how magento deals with email transaction